# Tool Shelf is not enabled

Tags: mesh

I am using 2.93.01.
I can not find "Tool Shelf".
Vertical toolbar is enabled [Select Box, Transform, Move/ Extrude, Bevel and...] but it's based on Edit Mode/Object Mode/...

I am macOS user and I'm watching a tutorial but I can't find this toolbar.
I have no control to Mesh tools, adding segments or other controls which is on older versions.

[image]

Comment: That side bar is different now, some tools are there (like transform) and some are by using right click or a shortcut (Shift + D = Duplicate), you could search for the tool that you need by pressing F3 and typing the name

Answer (score 0):

The old tool shelf code was disabled in Blender 2.8x as a double entry to the text menus in the header.

The adjust last operation panel at the end of the tool shelf is now a panel that pops up down left. It is closed by default. You need to open it now every time you want to adjust something.

This adjust last operation panel can also be called by a hotkey. It was formerly F6. Now it is F9.

[image]